# Javascript Jquery Scroll 1 page down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I dont really know how to explain but I would like to create a Website where with a small scroll on the mouse wheel, the site goes to the next anchor.

A good example for this is the tesla model 3 website on the US site https://www.tesla.com/model3

Does anyone know how to search for this in the internet or has some code examples?

Comment: Some jQuery plugin can do this: https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

Comment: thank you that's exactly what I looked for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is catch `.scroll()`-event inside body of the site and do `.scrollTop(value)` method of jQuery. I think it should be like that

```
// bind event to body
$('body').scroll(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.scrollTop($this.scrollTop() + $(window).innerHeight()); // set scroll position
});
```